# jboss_init_redhat is not working

Tags: java, linux, bash, jboss

I used Redhat and Jboss 4.2.2 GA for application server.

I have a basic problem that when I try to run

> ./jboss_init_redhat.sh start

is not working.

Basicly I want to run inside jboss_init_redhat.sh file;

> /opt/jboss/bin/run.sh -c X -b 0.0.0.0

This line is working but jboss_init_redhat.sh not working.That's our problem.

I checked all permissions but there is not any permission problem.

jboss_init_redhat.sh is below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# $Id: jboss_init_redhat.sh 60992 2007-02-28 11:33:27Z dimitris@jboss.org $
#
# JBoss Control Script
#
# To use this script run it as root - it will switch to the specified user
#
# Here is a little (and extremely primitive) startup/shutdown script
# for RedHat systems. It assumes that JBoss lives in /usr/local/jboss,
# it's run by user 'jboss' and JDK binaries are in /usr/local/jdk/bin.
# All this can be changed in the script itself. 
#
# Either modify this script for your requirements or just ensure that
# the following variables are set correctly before calling the script.

#define where jboss is - this is the directory containing directories log, bin, conf etc
JBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME:-"/opt/jboss"}

#define the user under which jboss will run, or use 'RUNASIS' to run as the current user
JBOSS_USER=${JBOSS_USER:-"jboss"}

#make sure java is in your path
JAVAPTH=${JAVAPTH:-"/usr/local/jdk/bin"}

#configuration to use, usually one of 'minimal', 'default', 'all'
JBOSS_CONF=${JBOSS_CONF:-"ikarus"}

#if JBOSS_HOST specified, use -b to bind jboss services to that address
JBOSS_HOST="0.0.0.0"
JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+"-b $JBOSS_HOST"}

#define the classpath for the shutdown class
JBOSSCP=${JBOSSCP:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jnet.jar"}

#define the script to use to start jboss
JBOSSSH=${JBOSSSH:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c $JBOSS_CONF $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR"}

if [ "$JBOSS_USER" = "RUNASIS" ]; then
  SUBIT=""
else
  SUBIT="su - $JBOSS_USER -c "
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -d "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  # ensure the file exists
  touch $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  if [ ! -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
    chown $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  fi 
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -f "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  echo "WARNING: location for saving console log invalid: $JBOSS_CONSOLE"
  echo "WARNING: ignoring it and using /dev/null"
  JBOSS_CONSOLE="/dev/null"
fi

#define what will be done with the console log
JBOSS_CONSOLE=${JBOSS_CONSOLE:-"/dev/null"}

JBOSS_CMD_START="cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin; $JBOSSSH"
JBOSS_CMD_STOP=${JBOSS_CMD_STOP:-"java -classpath $JBOSSCP org.jboss.Shutdown --shutdown"}

if [ -z "`echo $PATH | grep $JAVAPTH`" ]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVAPTH
fi

if [ ! -d "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  echo JBOSS_HOME does not exist as a valid directory : $JBOSS_HOME
  exit 1
fi

echo JBOSS_CMD_START = $JBOSS_CMD_START

case "$1" in
start)
    cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        eval $JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &" 
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        $JBOSS_CMD_STOP
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_STOP"
    fi 
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change JBOSS_USER information to `RUNASIS`, it should work properly.